# Should different questions be made for style and functional questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Ongoing example: [functional](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19153/review-c-algo-function), [style](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18982/review-c-algo-style).

As far as I know, focusing on any aspect of the code is fair game in a review.  Do we want to allow such specialised-duplicates and request reviewers to answer in the appropriate one?

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, no.  A key element of asking for a code review is asking "what is most wrong about this code?".  If reviewers tend to focus on a specific aspect, it likely means that this aspect stands out more than the rest.  Style does tend to do this simply due to its nature, but accepting the style criticisms, correcting where deemed justified, and then reposting with (significantly) updated code seems like a better idea than splitting the same question in two.